# Why won't scons look in ~/.scons/site_scons by default?

Tags: default, scons

I have a mystery here:  I'm using Ubuntu SCons  (package version 1.2.0.d20100117-1).  I have a directory `$HOME/.scons/site_scons/`, which all the documentation says should be one of the site directories searched by default.  There's a module subdirectory `fpga`.  In my project directory, I have an `SConstruct` file consisting solely of:

```
import fpga
```

Here's the oddity:  When I just run `scons`, I get the following error:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
ImportError: No module named fpga:
  File "BLAh/foo/SConstruct", line 1:
    import fpga
```

If I run `scons --site-dir=$HOME/.scons/site_scons`, which seems like it should be the default anyway, then everything works like a charm.

An additional oddity: When I run `strace scons`, it never tries to `stat` or `open` `$HOME/.scons` -- in fact the only place it looks for `site_scons` is `./site_scons`.

Has anyone else ever seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to update to a later version to get ~/.scons to automatically get picked up by SCons.

Here's the 1.2 docs, which don't mention the ~/.scons

http://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-man.html

Comment: Thanks.  Seems kind of obvious in retrospect!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the **site_scons** folder is supposed to be in the same folder as the **SConstruct** file. Then it works fine. The *--site-dir* option is there for when you have a machine-wide site_scons folder.

Comment: *"`$HOME/.scons/site_scons/`, which all the documentation says should be one of the site directories searched by default"*

Comment: @JonathonReinhart have you checked the [1.2 docs?](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user.html#AEN3627)

Answer (score 0):

After a fair bit of digging, on SCons 2.1.0.r5357, this will work if the site initialisation file is named:

`$HOME/.scons/site_scons/site_init.py`,

This certainly wasn't obvious from the documentation. If this continues to be a problem, for example with an alternative machine wide site, you can add some debug output in `SCons/Scripts/Main.py` in the `_load_site_scons_dir` function.